# NFS Mount Options on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, nfs, mount

I need to be able to mount an NFS file system on Solaris 10 using the equivalent of the `nolock` mount option. From what I can see this mount option is not available on Solaris (looks like its a Linux mount option).
There is an `llock` mount option but I can not find any doc whether this performs the same function as the `nolock` option on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The Solaris option `llock` is the one you want.  It means 'local locks'.  So the nfs client does use locks, but it's self-contained and doesn't impact other clients.